# Chai - check 2 objects arrays have same title

Tags: javascript, arrays, mocha.js, chai

Say I have 2 arrays containing objects:

```
var aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]

var bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900', other: 'someDetail' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200', other: 'someDetail' } ]
```

How can i verify that they have the same title values in each array, even when it's not in the same order?

Can i use something like:

`expect(aArray.title).to.deep.equal(bArray.title)`

Then for that matching title item, I want to check the price is the same between the two.

I've also tried 
`expect(cart).to.deep.include.members(cart2).but.not.own.deep.include.property('someDetail');`

Comment: I have not used `Chai`, but `aArray.title` will be undefined. I guess you can try something like `function getTitle(array) { return array.map(x => x.title);} expect(getTitle(aArray)).toEqual(getTitle(bArray))`

Comment: Sorry - updated my questions, array b has additional pieces of info

Comment: I don't know chai so wont be answering it, but you can definitely try something try like `function exists(array, title) { return array.some(x => x.title === title)}; expect(exists(bArray, aArray[index].title)).to.be(true)`

Comment: Looks like `expect(aArray.title).to.deep.equal(bArray.title)` actually does that. But I want the matching items to be checked on the `price` value to

Comment: Again as I said, I'm not a Chai user so these are pure JS ways. I'm just giving hints so some Chai user can provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it I guess. Here is a way which only requires you to map your `bArray` to only the objects with keys which you require, i.e. `title` and `price`.

Then you can use [`members`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) along with [`deep`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep). As you see, the same order of the array members is not required, but same keys are required.

```js
const aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]

const bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900', other: 'someDetail' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200', other: 'someDetail' } ]

const newBArray = bArray.map(({ title, price }) => ({ title, price }))

try {
  chai.expect(newBArray).to.have.deep.members(aArray)
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error!", e)
} finally {
  console.log("Done with execution.")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.1.2/chai.min.js"></script>
```

I've used try/catch/finally to make the code give valid hints about what is happening.

Comment: If `aArray` could also have other keys, however I only ever wanted to get title and price, I presume I just have to create `const newAArray`

Comment: Yes, exactly. You just need to make sure both arrays have objects with only the keys that you require.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get all the title from these two arrays.

And use [eql](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) to compare them.

```
var aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]
var bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900', other: 'someDetail' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200', other: 'someDetail' } ]

var aTitle = aArray.map(item => item.title);
var bTitle = bArray.map(item => item.title);

expect(aTitle).eql(bTitle)
```

#### Update

If you want to check `title` and `price` is matched, currently I think of one method would be easier.

You can concat the title and price as a string and compare them.

```
var aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]
var bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900', other: 'someDetail' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200', other: 'someDetail' } ]

var aTitle = aArray.map(item => `${item.title}|${item.price}`); // ['Abc|1,200', 'def|900']
var bTitle = bArray.map(item => `${item.title}|${item.price}`);
expect(aTitle).eql(bTitle);
```

Comment: Thanks - but for that specific matching one, if I want to check that the price is correct, can I do this with map?

Comment: @userMod2 I think you can wrap this as a method. I will update the answer. You can check it

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstand your further question. I will update it again.

Comment: @userMod2 You can check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` method on arrays.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

```
var aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]

var bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' } ]

var sameTitle = true;
aArray.forEach(function(objA){
    var titleMatch = bArray.find(function(objB){
        return objA.title === objB.title;
    })
    if(titleMatch === undefined) sameTitle = false;
})
console.log(sameTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

you verify by using this way.

```
 var aArray = [ { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' }, { title: 'def', price: '900' } ]

    var bArray = [ { title: 'def', price: '900' }, { title: 'Abc', price: '1,200' } ]


    for(i=0;i<aArray.length;i++){
        var CheckTitle=aArray[i].title;
        for(j=0;j<bArray.length;j++){
            var CheckTitle1=bArray[j].title;

            if(CheckTitle==CheckTitle1){
                alert("same title");
            }
            else{
                alert("diff title");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry - updated my questions, array b has additional pieces of info